# Context.ExecuteQuery() works on local machine but not in Azure Function app. Returns Error (400) Bad Request. Sharepoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, azure-functions

I had a script working in Windows Powershell ISE that copies all the folders and subfolders from a document library on one Sharepoint site over into a Document library with the same name on another sharepoint site. It works locally and am wanting to execute it inside an Azure Function App. I have the function created and have just been testing the code running it in 'run.ps1'. I keep getting an error on this line (highlighted in asterisk below) "$SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()".

**Error:**

Error Copying File! System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )--- End of inner exception stack trace ---at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) on line 46

**Code:**

```
param([string] $QueueItem, $TriggerMetadata)  

Write-Host "PowerShell queue trigger function processed work item: $QueueItem"
Write-Host "Queue item insertion time: $($TriggerMetadata.InsertionTime)"



#Load SharePoint Client Assemblies 
Try{

    Add-Type -Path "D:\home\site\wwwroot\InvokePnPSiteTemplate\bin\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"   
Add-Type -Path "D:\home\site\wwwroot\InvokePnPSiteTemplate\bin\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "D:\home\site\wwwroot\InvokePnPSiteTemplate\bin\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll" 
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}
  

$userId = "name@tenant.com"    
$plainText= "*******"  
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $plainText -AsPlainText -Force  
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd) 

 
 Function Copy-AllFilesWithMetadata
 {
   param
     ( 
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $SourceFolder,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $TargetFolder
     )

     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Source Folder: $SourceFolder Target Folder $TargetFolder"

   
     Try {
         #Get all Files from the source folder
         $SourceFilesColl = $SourceFolder.Files
         $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SourceFilesColl)
         **$SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()**
     
         #Iterate through each file and copy
         Foreach($SourceFile in $SourceFilesColl)
         {
             #Get the source file
             $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($SourceFolder.Context, $SourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl)
                 
             #Copy File to the Target location
             $TargetFileURL = $TargetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl+"/"+$SourceFile.Name
             [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($TargetFolder.Context, $TargetFileURL, $FileInfo.Stream,$True)
     
             #Copy Metadata field values
             $SourceListItem = $SourceFile.ListItemAllFields
             $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SourceListItem)
             $SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
                 
             #Get the new file created
             $TargetFile = $TargetFolder.Context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFileURL)
             $TargetListItem = $TargetFile.ListItemAllFields
                 
             #Set Metadata values from the source
             $Author =$TargetFolder.Context.web.EnsureUser($SourceListItem["Author"].Email)
             $TargetListItem["Author"] = $Author
             $Editor =$TargetFolder.Context.web.EnsureUser($SourceListItem["Editor"].Email)
             $TargetListItem["Editor"] = $Editor
             $TargetListItem["Created"] = $SourceListItem["Created"]
             $TargetListItem["Modified"] = $SourceListItem["Modified"]
             $TargetListItem.Update()
             $TargetFolder.Context.executeQuery()
     
             Write-host -f Green "Copied File '$($SourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl)' to '$TargetFileURL'"
         }
     
         #Process Sub Folders
         $SubFolders = $SourceFolder.Folders
         $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SubFolders)
         $SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
         Foreach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
         {
             If($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
             {
                 #Prepare Target Folder
                 $TargetFolderURL = $SubFolder.ServerRelativeUrl -replace $SourceLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, $TargetLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                 Try {
                         $Folder=$TargetFolder.Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFolderURL)
                         $TargetFolder.Context.load($Folder)
                         $TargetFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
                     }
                 catch {
                         #Create Folder
                         if(!$Folder.Exists)
                         {
                             $TargetFolderURL
                             $Folder=$TargetFolder.Context.web.Folders.Add($TargetFolderURL)
                             $TargetFolder.Context.Load($Folder)
                             $TargetFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
                             Write-host "Folder Added:"$SubFolder.Name -f Yellow
                         }
                     }
                 #Call the function recursively
                 Copy-AllFilesWithMetadata -SourceFolder $SubFolder -TargetFolder $Folder
             }
         }
     }
     Catch {
         $e = $_.Exception
$line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
$msg = $e.Message 

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error Copying File! $e on line $line"
        
     }
    
 }

  #Set Parameter values
 $SourceSiteURL="https://rothlochston.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectTemplateFinal"
 $TargetSiteURL="https://rothlochston.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectTest3"

     
 $LibraryNames="Project Technical","Project Commercial","Project Commercial Support"
     

     if ($SourceSiteURL -eq $null -or $TargetSiteURL -eq $null -or $userId  -eq $null -or $pwd -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Output "Somthing went wrong!"
        Write-Output "Some of the variables are not correct"
    }
else
    {
         Write-Output "Variables are correct"
         

 #Setup the contexts
 $SourceCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SourceSiteURL)
 $SourceCtx.credentials =  $creds
 $TargetCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($TargetSiteURL)
 $TargetCtx.credentials =  $creds
          
 #Get the source library and Target Libraries
   Foreach($LibraryName in $LibraryNames)
         {

 $SourceLibrary = $SourceCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
 $SourceCtx.Load($SourceLibrary)
 $SourceCtx.Load($SourceLibrary.RootFolder)
     
 $TargetLibrary = $TargetCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
 $TargetCtx.Load($TargetLibrary)
 $TargetCtx.Load($TargetLibrary.RootFolder)
  $TargetCtx.ExecuteQuery()

 

  #Call the function
     $Count = $SourceLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Count 

        If(($Count -eq $null))
            {
 Copy-AllFilesWithMetadata -SourceFolder $SourceLibrary.RootFolder -TargetFolder $TargetLibrary.RootFolder
  } 
     Else {
       Write-Host -f Red "`tA Document Library '$LibraryName' has folders."
     }

 }
    }
```

Is someone with experience able to tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `$SourceFolder.Context` you can use the SharePoint URL context (`$ctx`) **$context** . The share point URL ***context*** contains all access to the folders and subfolders.

```
    $ctx  =  New-Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
```

Here I have modified your code:

```
$userId  =  "name@tenant.com"
$plainText=  "*******"
$pwd  =  ConvertTo-SecureString  $plainText  -AsPlainText  -Force

#Set up the context
$ctx  =  New-Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$creds  =  New-Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId,  $pwd)

Function  Copy-AllFilesWithMetadata
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]  $SourceFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]  $TargetFolder
    )

    Write-Host  -ForegroundColor  Red  "Source Folder: $SourceFolder Target Folder $TargetFolder"

    Try {

    #Get all Files from the source folder

    $SourceFilesColl  =  $SourceFolder.Files

    #Removed this line of code
    #$SourceFolder.Context.Load($SourceFilesColl)
    #$SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
    
    #Added the context with Load() and ExecuteQuery()
    $ctx.Load($SourceFilesColl)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    ....
    }
```

Refer [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-file.html) for more information